# What are the requirements for housing an exterior gas water heater?

Tags: water-heater, structural, anchor

Recently, I had to remove the housing/stand for our 60 gallon exterior gas water heater for reasons I'll get to. The housing was integrated into the exterior wall of the house, and while initially it may have been well supported by the wall and a pair of 4x4 posts, ground settling occurred and the entire housing ended up getting pulled away from the wall. The results was water and insect intrusion.

Ground settling is a chronic issue in the area we live, and I'm trying to come up with a new way to raise and house the hot water heater when I reinstall it. But ultimately, I'd like to find a means of housing the water heater that doesn't overly rely on anchoring it to the newly replaced sheathing and siding. One idea I had is to install anchor block bolted into framing studs around which siding is cut and installed. The blocks would provide support but not create a water or air tight seal. Instead the siding would provide waterproofing for the wall and gravity drainage for the housing of any wind driven rain that happens to enter.

I'm also looking for some ideas on how to better support the water heater that doesn't rely on posts set in concrete opposite the wall, which is what failed previously. I'm considering a steel L-bracket with a 45 degree support. The principal anchor for the support would be at the bottom of the bracket where it would be attached to the building's cement foundation.

Just hoping for some feedback or insight from experience that anyone might provide.

Comment: Not knowing where you live, you may be a prime candidate for solar hot water. Then you can put the tank where it is convenient. Sometimes it may be on the roof.

Comment: I'm in coastal Texas. Would likely be ideal for a solar hot water heater, but I've never really seen them used in the US and wouldn't know where to begin. Do you have experience with solar water heaters or can you point me in a good direction to start?

Comment: Where on Texas coast? Which county? How often does it freeze there? Is this natural gas or LPG/propane?

Comment: Nueces county, natural gas, we've had extended hard freezes (4 days) the last two years.

Comment: So this is an exterior closet grafted onto the side of the house? Is there exterior siding on the back of the WH closet?  Is this original construction or was the water heater moved there later? Is the water heater accessed from outside or through a door from inside? What is inside the house opposite the water heater?

Comment: Having a gas fired tank WH outside the house is a great location to prevent damage if and when the WH has a catastrophic failure. The best WH for this situation would be an exterior wall mounted tankless WH, but the question at hand is how to support a tank WH. Modern exterior natural gas fired tankless water heaters require a connection to 120 V  ac power for electronic controls and perhaps for ignition. And changing to a tankless WH might require upgrading the gas service since the burner for the tankless to replace a 60 gal tank would require a gas flow about 4x higher. All this is costly.

Answer (score -2):

The best place to start is:
https://www.energy.gov/energysaver/solar-water-heaters
Solar hot water works in Michigan so I think Texas would have no problem.